# PHP defined method returns false value but static variable exists

Tags: php, static, constants, defined

Can someone explain this to me?

```
<?php 
class SomeClass {
  public static $SomeStatic = "SomeValue";
}

$class_name = "SomeClass";

var_dump("{$class_name}::\$SomeStatic"); // shows "SomeClass::$SomeStatic"

var_dump($class_name::$SomeStatic); // shows "SomeValue"

var_dump(defined("{$class_name}::\$SomeStatic")); // shows "bool(false)"
```

Why does defined method returns false? To think that the 2nd var_dump returns a value.

Comment: `defined()` -> [`Checks whether a given named` **constant** `exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) You don't have any constants here. (`static` !== `constant`)

Comment: how do you test if a static variable exists? isset method does not work..

Comment: Why doesn't `isset()` work? How do you try to use it?

Comment: @gptimajo: I've edited my answer with the correct way to check for static properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static variable isn't a constant, so `defined` returns `false`.

To check if a class has a static property, you can use this function:

```
function has_static_property($class, $property_name)
{
    $reflection        = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $static_properties = $reflection->getStaticProperties();

    return array_key_exists($property_name, $static_properties);
}
```

More information about the [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/class.reflectionclass.php) class and the [`getStaticProperties`](http://php.net/manual/reflectionclass.getstaticproperties.php) method can be found on the PHP documentation.

Comment: Why not just: `if(isset(SomeClass::$SomeStatic))` ?

Comment: returns a Fatal Error